# overlapping images one over another in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to overlap the two images such that the bottom image comes up to the top image.
Here is the code

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .col-md-6{
            margin: 1px; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6"><img src="top-header-1.png"></div>
                <div class="col-md-6"><img src="Base-BG_4.png"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is the attached screenshot

[image]

I want to be like this

[image]

Comment: you can use z-index

Comment: @can u plz write some lines of code?

Comment: for image which you want on top add style="z-index:100px" if you want another on top of this then just go on increasing z-index

Comment: @Ahefaz I added this  .under
        {
            position:absolute;
            left:0px;
            top:0px;
            z-index:-1;
          
            
        }
        .over
        {
            position:absolute;
          top:100%;
            z-index:-1;
        }    It made the width of top image reduce

Comment: for .over use higher value of z-index than .under

Comment: Please check this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Ahefaz still the same. I am attaching a screen shot , kindly check.

Answer (score 3):

You need to just add `position:absolute;` with `position:relative` as i used

```css
  .col-md-6{
   margin: 1px; 
 }
 
.picContainer {position:relative;}
.pic2 {position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;}
```

```html
<href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
 
 <div class="container-fluid picContainer">
    <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6"><img src="http://www.qygjxz.com/data/out/114/4676052-image.png"></div>
       <div class="col-md-6 pic2"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/04/06/11/50/image-editing-101040_960_720.jpg"></div>
   </div>
    </div>

    </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: thank you so much. But the over image is shifting upwards as I zoom in the window

Comment: You can fix that size

Comment: I didn't get you

Comment: I mean you can make that picture size as fixed then that picture will not shift upwards when zoom in the window

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can use `absolute` positioning for your requirement, I don't think it is the best way now. You can achieve it using simple margin adjustments.

I hope this is something that you are looking for.

HTML

```
<div class="header">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="image-container">

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header {
  width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('http://indianapublicmedia.org/arts/files/2012/04/sample-gates-9-940x626.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;

}
.image-container {
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('https://nikonrumors.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Nikon-1-V3-sample-photo.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Refer the [codepen](https://codepen.io/abinthaha/pen/EvXGPQ) sample